# Make a bar chart of the lengths of the words in“A long time ago,in a galaxy far,far away"

Tags: string-manipulation, charts, text

[image: The expected output and the output obtained both are same, but why is it showing it wrong. All the desired functions have been used.]

The expected output and the output obtained both are same, but why is it showing it wrong. All the desired functions have been used,

Comment: The WL auto-grader can be very picky about what it considers to be an acceptable answer. Is this question from a Wolfram-U course?

Comment: yes @RohitNamjoshi

Comment: I suggest reporting the issue to wolfram-u@wolfram.com.